# How to put matrix in a matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I am curious how I can make something similar to this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just chose the way to recreate your picture with the clone of Times New Roman.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[\exp(At_y)=\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(t \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}) & \begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}  & \exp(t(1)) 
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a `smallmatrix` you will have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[\exp(At_y)=\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(t \Bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)) & \begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}  & \exp(t(1)) 
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A last possibility with the `medsize` environment from `nccmath`:

```
\usepackage{nccmath} 
\newenvironment{medpmatrix}{\medsize\begin{pmatrix}}{\end{pmatrix}\endmedsize}
................
\[ \exp(At_y)=\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(t \begin{medpmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\[-0.4ex]
0 & 1 & 0\\[-0.4ex]
0 & 0 & 1
\end{medpmatrix}\mathrlap{)} & \begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix} & \exp(t(1))
\end{pmatrix} \]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. Thank you!

Comment: Don't you think a medium-sized inner matrix would look better?

Comment: @Bernard Very kind Bernard, do you think to a smallmatrix? :-)

Comment: No, smallmatrix is really too small.  I thought of `\medmath{...}` from `nccmath`, which is about 80 % of  \displaystyle. I often use `\mfrac` for numerical fractional coefficients.

Comment: @Bernard You as other users are authorized to modificate my code. Welcome :-) Now I'm doing a job for my friend in LaTeX.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've added my suggestion. Of course, if you're not convinced, feel free to remove it.

Comment: @Bernard I am convinced :-):-) :-) and thank you veryyyyyyyyyyyyyy muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
\[\exp(t A_J)=
\begin{pNiceArray}{CCCC}[margin]
 \Block{3-3}{\exp\left(t\,
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}
 \right)} & & & 0 \\
& \hspace*{1.5cm} & & 0 \\ 
&&&0\\
0 & 0& 0 & \exp\left(t(t)\right)
\end{pNiceArray}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will take this method into account.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\[
\exp(tA_J) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp\begin{pmatrix}t\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix} & \begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\\[1.5em]
\begin{matrix}0&0&0\end{matrix} & \exp(t(1))
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sebastiano have already added such an answer. By the way, why do you need `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` and `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`. It works for me even withou these lines.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` is for setting "times" as the default roman font, and `mtpro2` is a times-compatible math typsetting package, with a free "lite" version that you can download and use for free.

Answer (score 3):

My proposal. I prefer brackets for the matrices, because parentheses are already overused.

The trick is to nest matrices and to add a small vertical space between the two rows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\exp(tA_j)=\begin{bmatrix}
  \exp\left( t \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) &
  \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}
\\ \noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}
0\qquad 0\qquad 0 & \exp\bigl(t(1)\bigr)
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\exp(tA_j)=\begin{pmatrix}
  \exp\left( t \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) &
  \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}
\\ \noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}
0\qquad 0\qquad 0 & \exp\bigl(t(1)\bigr)
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have only just 3 votes.....and now they are 2...approved!